# form disappears when it is submitted in PHP

Tags: php

I've got the following in my code and I cant get to work the latter part of the code work. To be more precise on my question, this works the way I want up until I click `OneClick`. When that's done I get another form (form2) with a `TwoClick` submit button dynamically populated. The issue comes here. When I click the button `TwoClick` the whole 'form2' disappears. can some one throw me a clue as to where I have gone wrong?

Thanks.

```
    <?php session_start(); ?>
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="One">
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="#">
        <?php echo "<input type='text' name='txt1' id='txt1'>"; // This text box is dynamically populated ?>
              <input type="submit" name="sendone" id="sendone" value="OneClick">
    </form>
</div>

<div id="two">


            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['sendone']))
            {   if($_POST['txt1'] == '')
                {echo 'txt1 is empty!'; return;} else {$_SESSION['txt1'] = $_POST['txt1'];}

                        if(isset($_SESSION['txt1'])) 
                        echo $_SESSION['txt1']; 
                        echo "<form name='form2' method='post' action='#'><table border='1'><tr><td>form 2 is here!<br></td></tr><tr><td><input type='text' name='txt123' id='txt123'></td></tr> <tr><td><input type='submit' name='sendtwo' id='sendtwo' value='TwoClick'></td></tr></table></form>";



            }   
                        if(isset($_POST['sendtwo']))
                        if(isset($_POST['sendtwo'])) 
                        {
                            if($_POST['txt123'] == '')
                            {echo "Text box is empty..."; return;}
                        }               
                        ?>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are closing `</form>` here `</form>
        </div>`

Comment: You should place `session_start();` before any output

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Thanks Yogesh,, I just edited it..Typo!

Comment: @l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇƇhƐȓ0nè Hi how do you suggest I change that? Would that be a solution to my issue? thanks

Comment: you start the session on the top of page which get rid you from session error .. its not compulsory to write all php on the top ... you can also write anywhere .. because in many situation we need to write php in middle even at the end of the page

Comment: delete all spaces before `<?php session_start(); ?>`

Comment: @JohnEnglish Check out my answer. It was your **2x** `return;` that killed it.

Comment: @Ziarno Although the code in the question shows spaces, it's just a formatting issue and has no bearing on the problem. You are partially right about it though, that it cannot hold whitespace before `<?php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<?php
    session_start();
    function putForm2(){
    $myForm = "<form name='form2' method='post' action='#'><table border='1'><tr><td>form 2 is here!<br></td></tr><tr><td><input type='text' name='txt123' id='txt123'></td></tr> <tr><td><input type='submit' name='sendtwo' id='sendtwo' value='TwoClick'></td></tr></table></form>";
    return $myForm;
    }
?><!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
<head><title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="One">
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="#">
        <?php echo "<input type='text' name='txt1' id='txt1'>"; // This text box is dynamically populated ?>
              <input type="submit" name="sendone" id="sendone" value="OneClick">
    </form>
</div>

<div id="two">


            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['sendone']))
            {   if($_POST['txt1'] == '')
                {echo 'txt1 is empty!'; return;} else {$_SESSION['txt1'] = $_POST['txt1'];}

                        if(isset($_SESSION['txt1'])) 
                        echo $_SESSION['txt1']; 
                        echo putForm2();



            }   
                        if(isset($_POST['sendtwo']))
                        if(isset($_POST['sendtwo'])) 
                        {
                            if($_POST['txt123'] == '')
                            {
                                echo putForm2();
                                echo "Text box is empty..."; return;
                            }
                        }               
                        ?>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: tell me if this is solves your concern.

Comment: This may be what the OP needs, however you'll need to put `<?php session_start(); ?>` at the top and above everything. Otherwise, it will kick back an error message, I just tested it.

Comment: Another thing, don't forget to change `<DOCTYPE html>` to `<!DOCTYPE html>` with the `exclamation mark`, it was missing.

Comment: @Hezbullah Shah  BINGO! this is what I wanted. Thanks man. Kudos++ :)

Comment: nice. 
yeah Fred is also right. i made a quick solution so missed those. :)

Comment: @HezbullahShah I suggest you make the changes in your answer, so if and when this could serve someone with a similar problem, will have working code.

Comment: @JohnEnglish You're welcome. I'm glad it worked out for you, cheers.

Comment: @HezbullahShah and @JohnEnglish - Might I suggest something? If you change the `action="#"` to `action=""`, you won't get the (for example) `form.php#` (**#**) at the end of the URL. Might be something worth using.

Comment: @Fred Hell yeah I was wondering how to get rid that too! awesome. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @JohnEnglish Anytime ;-) enjoy

Answer (score 0):

1. `Session_start()` must be called before outputting any output (in the beggining of the script).
2. Sendtwo form disappears because of your logic - when you submit Sendtwo, `$_POST['sendone']` is *not* set, therefore not being echoed. To fix that you could for example change the first condition to:

`if (isset($_POST['sendone']) || isset($_POST['sendtwo']))`

Comment: I edited the code as above Ziarno. But the the concern is again when the validation text appears which is 'Text box is empty...' the form is hidden. How do I retain the message and the elements of the form2 also on the screen?

Comment: set `$_SESSION['txt1'] = 'txt1 is empty!'` instead of echoing it, if you always want form2 to appear after submitting form1

Comment: or just remove this condition `if(isset($_SESSION['txt1']))`

Comment: delete the `return` statements too

Answer (score 0):

try putting

```
if(isset($_POST['sendtwo']))
         if(isset($_POST['sendtwo'])) 
         {
             if($_POST['txt123'] == '')
                      {echo "Text box is empty..."; return;}
         }
```

at the very end. i mean after the last `}`

Comment: This works Hezbullah Shah, but again the issue is when the message is displayed the txt123 disappears. Any tips to retain both message and the txt123 when the sendtwo is submitted? Thank you.

Comment: if you enter nothing at the second form, you will get "Text box is empty..."

Comment: your code logic is like that. you have given the condition `if($_POST['txt123'] == '')`

Comment: @HezbullahShah Why are you also **repeating 2** `if(isset($_POST['sendtwo']))`? I'll never know.

Comment: that's a typing error. not needed twice.

Comment: u require something else?

Comment: Still hasn't got what I need cleared man! pls have a look at the comment I left with l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇ ƇhƐȓ0nè's answer.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this example and read the code comments. Though really its unclear to me what your trying todo so ive just ported code to what I think your trying todo, tho there are better ways handle processing forms. Also You should really think about your form value keys, txt1 and txt123 are not helpful and dont explain the type of variable you want from the form. Perhaps its of interest.

```
<?php 
session_start();
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $form = null;
    //Handle form 1
    if(isset($_POST['sendone'])){
        //reset session vars if new request
        unset($_SESSION['txt1']);
        unset($_SESSION['txt123']);

        //validate txt1
        if(!empty($_POST['txt1'])){
            //set into session
            $_SESSION['txt1'] = $_POST['txt1'];
            //or you could put the value in a <input type="hidden" name="txt1" value="'.htmlspecialchars($_POST['txt1']).'"/>

            $form = "
    <form name='form2' method='post' action=''>
        <table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <td>form 2 is here!<br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='text' name='txt123' id='txt123'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='submit' name='sendtwo' id='sendtwo' value='TwoClick'></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>";
        } else {
            $error['txt1'] = 'txt1 is empty!';
        }
    }

    //do second form
    if(isset($_POST['sendtwo'])){
        //validate
        if(!empty($_POST['txt123'])){
            //set session
            $_SESSION['txt123'] = $_POST['txt123'];
        }else{
            $error['txt123'] = 'txt2 is empty!';
        }
    }

    //check then do something with both form values
    if(empty($error) && isset($_SESSION['txt1']) && isset($_SESSION['txt123'])){
        $form = "Both txt1=".htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['txt1'])." and txt123=".htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['txt123'])." was set into session";
    }

}
?>
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="One">
        <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
            <input type='text' name='txt1' id='txt1'> 
            <input type="submit" name="sendone" id="sendone" value="OneClick"> 
            <?php echo isset($error['txt1'])?$error['txt1']:null;?>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="two">
      <?php echo isset($form)?$form:null;?>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for the time spent on this. But what I simply need is when then 'Text box is empty...' message shows on the sreen, the form2 elements which is in this case 'Form2 is here' text, the text box 'text123' and the submit button which is 'sendtwo' to be visible. In this code what happens is when the 'Text box is empty...' displays the form2 elements are hidden so that user has to hit back button on the browser to go back.